# Maven Cargo deployment to remote JONAS fails on already autoloaded war

Tags: maven, cargo, autodeploy, jonas

Here is the sequence of actions that leads to deployment failure :

- I deploy for the first time a war called xxx.war, through Cargo, to a remote JONAS 4.7.4. It succeeds, and put my war in webapps directory.
- I try to redeploy this war through Cargo to update it : no problem, it succeeds.
- I shutdown JONAS and start it. My JONAS is configured to autodeploy war that are in webapps directory. So my xxx.war is automatically deployed by JONAS.
- I try to redeploy a new version of this war through Cargo : this is a failure. When a war has been autodeployed by JONAS, I just can't redeploy it by Maven Cargo.

If JONAS is not in autodeploy mode, there is no problem in redeploying a new version of the war through Cargo after a restart of JONAS.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I don't use cargo anymore.

Instead I do deployment through antrun plugin, and it works very well.

I have put JONAS in autodeploy mode.

```
        <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
            <tasks>
                <scp 
                    file="${project.basedir}/target/${war.warName}.war"
                    todir="${scp.finalDir}" 
                    trust="true" 
                    failonerror="true"/>
            </tasks>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
                <execution>
                      <id>copy-war-to-server</id>
                      <phase>install</phase>
                      <goals>
                             <goal>run</goal>
                      </goals>
                </execution>
         </executions>
       <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.42</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
   </plugin>
```